# I/O error while reading input message; nested exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException

Tags: rest, spring-boot

I can post input data using postman where as if I use the following code it's throwing an I/O error while reading the input message: nested exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException(400)

```
$http({
    method: "POST",
    url: '/user',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'},
    data: updateEmp
    }).success(function (response) {
        refresh();
    }).error(function (response) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
        //alert("There some problem while fetching.");
    });
```

[image]